# Reversing the sorting order of the newest product filter in magento

Tags: mysql, sorting, filter, magento-1.9, configurable-product

I have added a newest filter to my Magento store using the below queries.

```
UPDATE `catalog_eav_attribute`
SET `used_for_sort_by` = 1
WHERE attribute_id = (SELECT ea.attribute_id FROM `eav_attribute` ea WHERE `entity_type_id` = (SELECT `entity_type_id` FROM `eav_entity_type` WHERE `entity_model` = "catalog/product") AND `attribute_code` = "created_at")


UPDATE `eav_attribute`
SET frontend_label = "Newest"
WHERE `entity_type_id` = (SELECT `entity_type_id` FROM `eav_entity_type` WHERE `entity_model` = "catalog/product") and `attribute_code` = "created_at";
```

The filter for sorting is reflecting in the front end, but it is showing the old product first and the new products in the last, Can anyone tell me how can i change this sorting order?

Answer (score 0):

By default it will be sorted as ascending, you can change it from       file : app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/List.php before setting the  collection

```
protected function _beforeToHtml()
{
    $toolbar = $this->getToolbarBlock();

    // called prepare sortable parameters
    $collection = $this->_getProductCollection();

    // use sortable parameters
    if ($orders = $this->getAvailableOrders()) {
        $toolbar->setAvailableOrders($orders);
    }
    if ($sort = $this->getSortBy()) {
        $toolbar->setDefaultOrder($sort);
    }
    if ($dir = $this->getDefaultDirection()) {
        $toolbar->setDefaultDirection($dir);
    }
    if ($modes = $this->getModes()) {
        $toolbar->setModes($modes);
    }

    /************  Our Condition   ***********/
    if($sort == 'created_at'){
       $toolbar->setDefaultDirection('desc');
    }

    // set collection to toolbar and apply sort
    $toolbar->setCollection($collection);
```

And do make sure to overwrite this file before doing the changes.